# Printing the longest user names

Tags: shell, scripting

I would like to know whether is a way to print the longest name of the usernames in linux. Can it be done?

Comment: The title and text conflict.  Do you want the longest username, or the longest real name? The text says "longest _name_ of the usernames", which seems to mean something other than the actual username.

Comment: What if there are two usernames that are the same length? Print both or just one? If this is homework, please give us the complete text of the assignment.

Answer (score 4):

To get the longest username (and its length):

```
$ getent passwd | awk -F':' '{ print length($1), $1 }' | sort -rn | head -n 1
11 _traceroute
```

That is, get the `passwd` file, compute the length of each username (the 1st `:`-delimited string), sort by length and pick the first.

If there are several usernames of the same length, the one that sorts last lexicographically is picked.

To get the longest real name (and see what username its the real name of, and the length):

```
$ getent passwd | awk -F':' '{ print length($5), $1, $5 }' | sort -rn | head -n 1
32 _rtadvd IPv6 Router Advertisement Daemon
```

This does the same thing as the first command, but it computes the length of the 5th `:`-delimited string in the `passwd` file. This field contains the real name of the user.  The output is the length of the real name, the username, and the real name.

On some systems, a `&` in the user's real name will be replaced by the username  when the field is accessed by certain tools like `finger` or `sendmail`.  For example, a `passwd` entry may be

```
operator:*:2:5:System &:/operator:/sbin/nologin
```

To take this into account when calculating the length of the real name:

```
getent passwd | awk -F':' '{ gsub("&", $1, $5); print length($5), $1, $5 }' | sort -rn | head -n 1
```

Further letting `awk` select the longest name, getting rid of the `sort` and `head`:

```
getent passwd |
awk -F':' '
          { gsub("&", $1, $5) ; len = length($5)      }
len > max { line = $0         ; max = len;            }
END       { split(line, a, FS); print max, a[1], a[5] }'
```

With this code, the *first found* longest name will be picked if there are several names of the same length.

Comment: Possible typo. I think you mean: "(the 1st `:` delimited string)" as the output of `getent` is delimited by `:`.

Comment: @NasirRiley Yep, that's my finger slipping off the shift key. Thanks.

Comment: With GNU awk > 4.0 you could do the sorting and selection natively e.g. `gawk -F: '{a[$1]=length($1); next} END {PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc"; for(x in a) {print x; break}}'`

Comment: @steeldriver I added another way of doing it.

Comment: `getent passwd` might not enumerate all the possible usernames. If, for instance, you're using sssd accessing an Active Directory domain, only the entries in /etc/passwd will be shown even though many other accounts have access to the system. I don't know of any any to enumerate these accounts to find the longest username. I would assume in my environment that the longest account name is the AD length limit of 20 characters but I cannot confirm that.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty unoptimized, but since you don't usually have tens of thousands of users in a slow database, it might do:

```
getent passwd | cut -d: -f1 \
| grep $(getent passwd | cut -d: -f1 | tr '[:print:]' '.' | sort | tail -n1)
```

Let's unpick this thing a bit: `getent passwd` will list the user database. The lines in there are of the form

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

Username, `x`, UID, GID, GECOS (usually Human-readable user name now), home directory, shell. We use `cut -d:1 -f1` to cut away everything but the first `:`-delimited field, i.e. the username.

In total, we're doing that twice: once to find the length of the longest username (line 2) and then to actually find usrenames of this length.

To find the length of the longest username, we just use `tr` to swap all characters for `.`s. Then, we can simply sort the list and know that the longest string of `.`s is last, so we obtain that with `tail -n1`. (Technically this requires that there's always at least one user, but there's root, so that's a fairly safe assumption.)

Now we have a string of dots that is as long as the longest user name. We're lucky it's dots, because `.` is the wildcard for "any character" for regular expressions, so we use `grep` to match all usernames against this string of spaces, and only the longest will match.

(FWIW, on my CentOS box, it was `systemd-network`.)

If you want the human-readable names, you basically just want `cut -d: -f5` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I have a file that contains first name, last name, and email address of users.  Here is what I did to print the longest first name:

```
awk '{print length($1), $1}' filename | sort -nr | head -1| cut -d\  -f2
```

Feel free to tweak it per your preference.  Note that you hit two spaces after `-d\`

To print the longest username, you can use

```
grep -v "^#" /etc/passwd | awk -F: '{print length($1), $1}' | sort -nr | head -1 | cut -d\  -f2
```

To print the real user name, use

```
grep -v "^#" /etc/passwd | awk -F: '{print length($5), $5}' | sort -nr | head -1 | cut -d\  -f2-
```

You put a dash after `-f2` at the end to make sure that you get spaces in the user's real name.

Answer (score 0):

Below are Top 10 longest usernames excluding the system users

```
sed -n '/sbin/!p' /etc/passwd|  awk -F ":" '{print length($1),$1}'| sort -k1 -nr| head
```

output

```
   9 praveen10
9 lost_foud
8 p2_final
7 praveen
6 p1_new
5 user5
5 user4
5 user3
5 user2
5 user1
```

Comment: This does not take into account the possibility of users authenticated though LDAP, Active Directory, or any other remote authentication source.